# Signalr with android client

Tags: android, signalr, signalr.client

Hi I'm new to Signalr and I want to develop android native client application for communicate with signalr server. So I follow  ["whathecode"](https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/getting-started-with-the-java-signalr-sdk/) article and still i'm not able to connect to server. Anyone can give me some sample project or example.Its big help for me. 
 
 Thank you.

```
public void connect(){

        HubConnection con = new   HubConnection(Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:3227/").toString());
        HubProxy hub = con.createHubProxy("MyHub1");
        con.start();
        try {
            hub.invoke( "Send", "user", "Hello world!" ).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Handle ...
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // Handle ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: So have you tried to solve this yourself and ran into a problem? What error did you get? Can you show some code?

Comment: Hi aberna, I'v update my code section. Thats what i simply do.

Comment: I'v got this error message : 
NegotiationException: There was a problem in the negotiation with the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I face same issue like you but it resolved by adding 3227 part to allow all connection from it in my windows firewall settings .

I also suggest instead of creating localhost use some ip and create SignalR server, after that it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void createConnections() {

        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
        String host = "http://192.168.0.63/SignalRServerApp/signalr";
        final HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(host, false);
        final HubProxy hp = connection.createHubProxy("MyHubController");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), SampleWork.getStringData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println(SampleWork.getStringData());

        SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = connection.start();
        try {

            EditText text = (EditText) getActivity()
                    .findViewById(R.id.text);

            String data = text.getText().toString();
            awaitConnection.get();
            try {
                hp.invoke("ReceiveData", data);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
            //Calling a server method named "Acknowledge" 
            hp.on("Acknowledge", new SubscriptionHandler1<String>() {

                @Override
                public void run(final String p1) {
                    //Here u gets the response from server

                }

            }, String.class);

            System.out.println("Test");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }`enter code here`
```